# Are there rules for making Class specific Custom Powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Please see above.

I'd like to make a Rogue encounter power akin to "One Two Punch" but for ranged attacks. This will be for those Two Fisted shooters and thrown weapons savants. Basically I made this this and I'd like some feed back on it.

> **Double Tap or Twin Knock: Rogue Attack (1 or maybe 3)**
>   *Those unaware will soon get the point.*
>   **Encounter: Martial, Weapon**
>   **Standard Action, Ranged Weapon**
>   **Requirements**: ranged weapons
>   **Target**: 1 or 2 creature with range
>   **Attack**: Dex vs AC
>   **Hit**: 1[W] in damage. If both targets are hit apply Sneak Attack damage to each target instead of just one.
>   **Special**: if user has the Backstab Utility, than extra damage is applied to both targets as well.

Comment: No, there are no guidelines for making custom powers. And I think you're still confused about the types of rogues; thieves get backstab, scoundrels get encounter powers, and never the twain shall meet.

Answer (score 2):

There are no rules for creating homebrew powers. However, what your proposing, though niche isn't bad for an encounter power.

1. The comparable power one-two punch makes this an equivalent power, you just don't get the light blade support. The only thing I can see here is the potential abuse of crossbow support, but that's only a factor in heroic (it's equaled by two weapon support in paragon and beyond). One-two punch is a fairly weak encounter for a rogue at L1. It's graded out at black by the char-op folks.
2. Thieves don't get at-wills (unless they are human) and Scoundrel rogues don't get Backstab (unless they take the feat Thief's backstab which swaps an encounter power for it). That makes this power incredibly niche, but that's fine for you if you're building it just for your purposes.

Counter to my previous thoughts, this is not overpowered, if it's anything it's under powered. Typically rogue encounter powers are about two things. Big single target damage and inflicting debilitating status effects that cause the target to grant combat advantage. This does neither of these things so it really doesn't fit the typical rogue ideal, but if it fits your theme, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

### No, there are no guidelines to create custom powers.

However, there is a way to achieve the flavor of your power using RAW as early as Rogue level 9, against a single target at least. I'm sure there are other combos but this is the one I'm familiar with.

- The level 9 Rogue daily power [Knockout](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1010) knocks a creature
  unconscious (save ends) or until it takes damage.
- The heroic tier
  feat [Two-Fisted Shooter](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=826) allows you to make a free attack with
  your offhand crossbow on a crit.
- Either [Slaying Action](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=818) (heroic
  tier feat) or the Sniper Action feature of the [Cloaked Sniper](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=181)
  paragon path allow you to deal sneak attack damage again on an action
  point.

Now with a melee weapon in the mainhand and a hand crossbow in the offhand, do this:

1. Attack with knockout, dealing sneak attack damage (you do have CA, right?)
2. Action point to [coup de grace](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=325) the sleeping target with a power of your choice (dealing sneak attack damage again).
3. Your hit turns into a crit automatically, and you get a second attack with your offhand hand crossbow.

And there you have it, the RAW one-two punch or double-tap.